# Urls contain illegal characters are not mapping to controllers in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

currently I have a url mapping in grails like this:

```
"/foo/$token/external"(controller: "hello") {...}
```

this works fine when incoming requests are like this:

```
"/foo/12345/external"
```

however, the token can contain characters like '/'. I tried to urlencode the token value so '/' would become %2f:

```
123/45 --> 123%2f45
```

but this did not get matched by grails.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the answer to the question, but I think you should just change it so that the tokens don't contain these types of characters.